# When is it okay to add "re" before a verb?

Tags: verbes, préfixes

*Revenir*, *repleuvoir*, *redevoir*… along with many others, these are verbs which I've come across that simply mean the same as the root verb + “again.”

But then you have words like “*resavoir*” and “*se ressouvenir*” which do *not* mean the same as the root verb.

When is it okay to add a “*re*” before a verb? Can it be done to every verb in the French language, or is it only for the pre-existing cases, words which are already established as repeat verbs?

Comment: resavoir doesn't exists, ressouvenir sound odd. But people would say "se rappeler" (like re-membering ;-) )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, the *re-* prefix doesn't always connote *re*-petition (e.g. *recompter*), it may also indicate *re*-currence (e.g. *rebondir*), *re*-action (e.g. *rebondir* with a different meaning), *re*-adjustment (e.g. *rehausser*), or state *re*-covery (e.g. *revenir*), *re*-ciprocity (e.g. *redevoir*), [among others](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/re-).

Quite a few verbs do not admit such a prefix. I would advise you against making words you have never seen. Prefer adverbial locutions such as “*de nouveau*”, “*à nouveau*”, “*une fois de plus*”, “*encore une fois*” to express repetition.

Note: *resavoir* does not exist, it sounds very odd and would not be understood (with whatever meaning); *reconnaitre* exists but its meaning is very different from *connaitre*.

Comment: *re-* is a productive prefix. You can add it before any verb that denotes an action (and many verbs that don't), and the meaning will be “do again” unless the verb already exists with a different meaning.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of pre-existing case (everyday use) of verbs with *re-* before: *rebondir*, *rejaillir*, *retordre*, *retrousser*…

But the *re-* form enables you to make new verbs with a meaning of repetition or not, which are not provided (directly) by the French language. You can use the *re-* before a verb with almost every verbs or nouns in French.

A very good article form the *Office Québécois de la langue française*: [le préfixe re-](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1677).

Or some examples in the french [Wikitionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/re-).

Comment: Note: *rebondir* does not exactly mean *bondir de nouveau*, *rejaillir* does not mean *jaillir de nouveau*. *Trousser* is barely used anymore, *retrousser* does not mean *trousser de nouveau*.

Comment: And there are cases where both verbs actually have more or less the same meaning: _[culer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/culer)_ is a specific boating term which essentially means the same as _reculer_.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in most cases and it should be understood: *reparler*, *remonter*, *revoir*, *reprendre*, *recourir*, *relire*…

but it will sound weird in some cases, even if it makes sense: *raimer* (aimer), *se révanouir*, *rehaïr*, *repréférer*, *recomprendre*…

and in some cases it means something else entirely: *réviser*, *reporter*, *remiser*, *répondre*, *ressentir*, *regarder*… and in this case, adding another *re-* will sound awkward.

So I would advise to do it in informal context, and especially orally: native speakers do it all the time, I have even heard « *J'ai re-ressenti* » and « *J'ai re-regardé* » ; but you shouldn't try it in formal context, or in write it if you are not sure of how it sounds. Note that it should be *ré-* before a silent *h* as in *réhabituer* and in some cases before a vowel *réarmer*, *réapprendre*.

For more insight on using *re-*, [le wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/re-) has good usages notes.

Now if you are not sure or don't want to use *re-*, in most cases, and especially for dynamic verbs, using *encore* is a good replacement in composite tenses

> *J'ai **re**​joué → J'ai **encore** joué*

while *de nouveau* sounds right in simple tenses

> *Je **re**​joue → Je joue **de nouveau**​*