# If someone "se resservir deux fois", does the person have three servings in total, not two?

Tags: sens, préfixes

> « Elle **s’est resservie** de ma quiche **deux fois**. »

This is kind of confusing to me because of the presence of the prefix *re*(sservir).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

She had three servings, just like *elle est revenue deux fois* implies *elle est venue trois fois*.

> Elle s'est servie → elle s'est servie (au moins) une fois.
>
> Elle s'est resservie → elle s'est servie deux fois
>
> Elle s'est resservie deux fois → elle s'est servie trois fois

See also [When is it okay to add "re" before a verb?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2750/when-is-it-okay-to-add-re-before-a-verb)

Comment: Elle est venue trois fois is the same as elle est revenue dois fois?

Comment: @Lambie if we focus on the number of times she came somewhere, yes.

Comment: It is not the same thing linguistically to say: She came here three times and she came back twice. That's all I'm saying. No worries.

Comment: @Lambie I agree, same in French.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the person had 3 servings:

---

**Se Resservir** means to **Re**fill (not exact, but works with this)

---

So with this logic, it means that the person served themselves once, then they refilled their plate twice:
1 + 2 = 3

So the individual had 3 servings

Comment: Refill is for drinks. refill a  plate is not idiomatic, really.

Answer (score 0):

En toute rigueur, elle a eu trois parts de quiche.

Dans la vie courante, la répétition (resservi, deux fois) sert souvent à appuyer le discours et non à noter l'accumulation. Dans ce cas, il est fort probable qu'elle n'ait eu que deux parts de quiche.

On trouve aussi cela avec le verbe réitérer par exemple.

Answer (score -1):

In English, we say **helpings** of food.
She had three helpings of my quiche.

Or: She helped herself three times to my quiche.

When you have re for food, it means a second time. se servir = one  helping, se resservir, two helpings.

But bear in mind, not every verb in French with RE means more than one. It can get pretty tricky. Just one quick example: Elle a remonté la rue......She went up the street OR She went back up the street. Only the context will allow you to decide which is right.

Comment: "Monter la rue" doesn't exist as far as I know, so "remonter la rue" will always mean "to go up the street".

Comment: Of course, monter la rue doesn't exist. To go UP the street, therefore it is not "go back  up the street". That is a very good example of RE not meaning adding another piece to the pie. As in resservir, where it does.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a colloquial translation would be "She came back for seconds of my quiche twice", thus implying she had 3 servings.